# BlackBerry push notifications: Is TomCat / MySQL really needed?

Tags: java, blackberry, push, blackberry-push

There doesn't seem to be a huge amount of information regarding BlackBerry's push technology. The only thing I wish to accomplish is to send notifications to blackberry devices as they become available.
Do I really need TomCat and MySQL for this? My java program is not a servlet and for the web-side of things I use PHP and communicate to java via sockets.

I am using java and if anyone knows of some examples, that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any language to push to the server. The only thing you need is the PAP file provided in the demo APP in the PUSH SDK

You need to send the PAP file throught http with your given credential by RIM.

Edit : Tomcat and Mysql are needed only if you want to install your own PUSH server with your BES environment. See the [Docs for DebugPortal](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/14464/BlackBerry_Push_Service_SDK-Development_Guide--925871-0316052041-001-1.0.0.5-US.pdf) on page 20

Here is the PAP file.

```
--$(boundary)
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pap PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD PAP 2.0//EN" 
    "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/pap_2.0.dtd" 
    [<?wap-pap-ver supported-versions="2.0"?>]>
<pap>
<push-message push-id="$(pushid)" ppg-notify-requested-to="$(notifyURL)">

<address address-value="WAPPUSH=$(pin)%3A100/TYPE=USER@rim.net"/>
<quality-of-service delivery-method="$(deliveryMethod)"/>
</push-message>
</pap>
--$(boundary)
$(headers)

$(content)
--$(boundary)--
```

Comment: Right, I just saw a script in which someone used CURL to send information through HTTP. That makes my life easier - I do have one more question for the "Best Answer". Why would the documentation make it seem like MySQL and Tomcat were a pre-requisite?

Comment: @Submerged see the DebugPortal in the docs http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/14464/BlackBerry_Push_Service_SDK-Development_Guide--925871-0316052041-001-1.0.0.5-US.pdf