# Blackberry push notification tutorial

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-push

I have registered with RIM for the push notification evaluation. But i cant find good sources for implementing push notifications. There are some samples in the sdk but i couldnt find out a way to implement them. So, i am looking for a good tutorial where i could find step by step implementation of push notification services...

Comment: You sure you read the SDK? Because RIM provide all the exemple you need. Do you have a more specific question ?

Comment: I have never done server side scripting. So understanding the server side scripting is difficult for me...I need detail steps of running the notification samples...

Comment: Could you install SDK of push application on blackberry??? I find a problem with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RIM's samples for the server side involve setting up a web application container (e.g. Tomcat), setting up a backend database, and then building their Spring-based application. This sample web app handles things like device registration, content subscription, etc. and features a portal to manage everything.

The bare minimum that is required, though, is to send a WAP Push message which is just an HTTP POST to their Push Service servers. [Here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/standalone-server-side-example-based-on-the-new-blackberry-push/td-p/492669) is a thread from the BlackBerry Support Forums that describes how to use their low-level PAP API to construct this message. Pay attention in particular to the messages by the user `mdicesare`.

There's also another SO question that has some [tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945004/blackberry-push-notifications-is-tomcat-mysql-really-needed).

Comment: Well, mdicesare is one of the author of BlackBerry's push service after all.