# Blackberry Push Notification implementation steps

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I am going to develop a Push notification application in Blackberry (OS 5.0 ,6.0). I did little R-n-D on Blackberry Push notification services.

1. Covers all the basic Info
   https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_services/push_overview.html
2. Push Essentials VS Push Plus 
   https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/platform_services/push_features.html
3. I have registered for Dummy application
   https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8121
4. I installed the Push SDK, Provided by RIm
   http://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/installing_the_sdk.html#jza1355764941890

Now My question are :

1. How I integrate the push SDK with my BB Eclipse?
2. How I test the push notification service?
3. And what is the difference between BB push Service vs Urban Airship service?  I know how to implement Urban Airship BB api ,but this time I don't want to use Urban Airship.
4. If we implement for live, what is the pricing difference between above mentioned service.  Because i have'nt found any pricing doc, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Perhaps you want to research this a bit more, then come back when you are stuck with one question, rather than four. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987301/blackberry-push-notification-tutorial

Comment: Is above steps work for BB10 apps also? As I am porting my android source code to BB10. If you have any links and references please share..