# How to integrate with Blackberry Push Service from .NET

Tags: .net, blackberry, blackberry-push

Is there a simple way to initiate push messages to RIM's "Blackberry Push Service" from .NET? The documentation only discusses using the [Java SDK](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/pushapi.jsp). I'm not familiar with how to interop with Java from .NET (and I can't find any documentation on the raw webservices), so if anyone has any guidance or experience to share it would help a lot.

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945004/blackberry-push-notifications-is-tomcat-mysql-really-needed/2945043#2945043

Comment: Yeah, I saw that post, it seems to be alluding to interfacing with the raw webservices, which isn't documented anywhere that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these links to the BB Developer Forum for further information regarding .NET development.

[A thread containing some code samples for C# .NET](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Pushing-to-application-push-and-forget/td-p/455873)

[Sample applications demonstrating BlackBerry push technology](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Sample-applications-demonstrating-BlackBerry-push-technology/ta-p/446054)

There is also a Blackberry Web Plug-In for Visual Studio 2008 which can be found [here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/eclipseplugin.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

The RIM Java-based push SDK has been ported to C# and is hosted - open source - on the CodePlex web-site [here](http://blackberrypushsdk.codeplex.com/).